# Parallelizing lines (commands, processes...) on a Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, parallel-processing, background-process

I am managing a **WiFi** network with multiple **repeaters** (access points).
I have made a script that counts the number of connected users on each one. Example for AP 1 and 2:

```
luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 1
3
luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 2
10
```

But it is a bit **slow**. Example for AP 3:

```
luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ time ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 3
5
real    0m7.074s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.040s
```

So, as long as I have more than 10 APs, I would like to **parallelize** all the readings. I have made another script that calls the individual requests in **background**. Something like:

```
AP-1=$(./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 1) &
AP-2=$(./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 2) &
AP-3=$(./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 3) &
... etc
sleep 20    # Wait 20 seconds for all readings to finish.
echo "$AP-1, $AP-2, $AP-3... etc"
```

But this does not seem to work. At least on **shell** tests:

```
luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ echo $a

luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ a=$(./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 4)
luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ echo $a
6
luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ unset a
luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ echo $a

luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ a=$(./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 4) &
[1] 13527
[A few minutes later...]
luis@Fresoncio:~/Temporal/ClientesActivos$ echo $a

[1]+  Done                    a=$(./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh 4)
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the method to **parallelize individual lines** in a shell script? Is **background processing** the right method?

Further data:

- My shell is **Bash**, but generic answers would be useful too.

Comment: Make your asynchronous scripts write to files rather than assign to variables (the latter is probably impossible).

Comment: I was thinking about it too, @n.m. but that would require some more programming (to check if the file is already full with data, not only created but empty, and so on), so I was wondering if there was an easier way. If there is no better method, I will use it. Thanks you.

Comment: No, make them write to different files, one file per job.

Comment: your variable names `AP-1` should fail. try a simple test first `AP-1=xyz` . I get `AP-1=xyz: not found [No such file or directory]`, while `AP_1=xyz` works fine. Other advice about parallel and others looks fine. Good luck.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using `wait` instead of `sleep`. `wait` is designed to work with back-grounded tasks. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html)

Example:

```
parallel ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh ::: $(seq 1 5)
```

Comment: A powerful solution, thanks you. And you can add parameters, like in `./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -c -t 15 ::: $(seq 1 5)`. Thanks you.